# wxPython Altering Native Window Styles

Tags: python, wxpython, native, nativewindow

One of the things I like about Google Chrome is that the tabs are placed in the top bar so that precious viewing space is conserved. I was wondering if wxPython facilitated the placing of widgets in the native OS's top bar. Similar to how Chrome places tabs in the native OS's topbar.

The program I'm currently writing is intended for netbooks and laptops, so space is at a premium.

Chrome in Windows 7:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. Perhaps in future version of wx, but this is some "custom" thing that Chrome does.